# In my reactjs, I initially used palette mosaic font . I changed the font to architect daughter but it is not changing . What is the problem?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I created html page using node.js and react.js with the help of vs code.
Here is the code I followed.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Architects+Daughter&family=Palette+Mosaic&display=swap');

.container {
  font-family: Architects Daughter;
}

h3 {
  color: brown;
}
```

This is the result I got
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Klqbm.png)

Comment: Where did you import the font? Can you share the code

Comment: From Google fonts